# Insert value into 3rd column by calculating difference of SUM of other column in sql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a query that runs Ok but doesn't create the desire results, I want this query to insert value in third column of my table (`PAYABLE_AMOUNT_DUE`) by taking difference of the SUM of second column (`PAYABLE_AMOUNT`) on the basis of it's ACTION string (`PAYABLE_ACTION`). Structure of my table is as shown below and the values,

[image: TABLE PAYABLES]

the logic yet I used is as below, but it doesn't insert the desired value into third table (as can see it's always 0)

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO `payables`(`payable_action`, `payable_amount`, `payable_amount_due`) 
VALUES ('Cash Closed', '300', 
      '(SELECT SUM(payable_amount)
               FROM payables
               WHERE payable_action = 'Cash In') -
       (SELECT SUM(payable_amount)
               FROM payables
               WHERE payable_action = 'Cash Closed')
        ')
```

As you can see it inserted value in `payable_amount` and in `payable_action` but not in `payable_amount_due`, I don't know why and how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised the above statement even parsed, as you have quotes around the SELECT statement and there are embedded quotes as well. In addition, I don't believe you can use SELECT expressions as VALUES arguments.

Comment: why not? while there is value in those columns! I guess it is possible, just give it a try :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right. I misunderstood and misstated the restriction. You *can* use SELECT in a VALUES expression. Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html, what you can't do is use SELECT in a subquery with the same table you are inserting into. The answer you accepted does not involve a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
INSERT INTO payables( payable_action, payable_amount, payable_amount_due ) 
SELECT 'Cash Closed', '300', 
        SUM( payable_amount * (payable_action='Cash In' ) ) 
          - SUM( payable_amount * (payable_action='Cash Closed') ) 
FROM payables
```

Edit: What this line does?

```
SUM( payable_amount * ( payable_action='Cash In' ) )
```

For every row `(payable_action='Cash In')` returns boolean, but mysql has just 0 or 1 for booleans, so we will be adding to the sum `payable_action * 1` for rows satisfying action condition and `payable_action * 0` for other rows. So basically only those with proper action will count.

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked just as I desired. Thanks once again :) Can you explain what this line do? SUM(payable_amount * (payable_action = "Cash In"))?